# Unable to download all images using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm not very familiar with data scrapping and I'm unable to download images using beautiful soup.

I need to download all images from a website. I'm using code below:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'http://someurl.org/'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# img_tags = soup.findAll('img')
img_tags = soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})

print('img_tags: ')
print(img_tags)

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

print('urls: ')
print(urls)

for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative 
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens 
            # to be the site variable atm. 
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

However this is ignoring all images present on the page that have html similar to this:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: thumbURL() }" src="/assets/images/submissions/abfc-2345345234.thumb.png">
```

I assume it is because of the data attribute also containing string "src" but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If that's the actual HTML code there's unbalanced quotation marks in it.  So you would want to retrieve all img tags with a data-bind value and you'll have to pull out the correct value.

Comment: I just edited, I had accidentally removed the quotation but that is what I see when inspecting the page.

Comment: how far does it go? does it print `img_tags`, or `urls`?

Comment: It does print img_tags and urls but completly ignores the images I care for and only prints social media icon images in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use selenium or some that can run javascript. This is the code load image until found it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

site = 'http://phylopic.org/'
dr = webdriver.Chrome()

dr.get(site)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, 20, 0.5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "span1"))
    )
except:
    print("Wait a bit more")
    time.sleep(5)

text = dr.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
print(imgs)

dr.close()
```

The second problem is how to convert a relative path to an absolute path. There are a few types of [relative path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) on `HTML`.

When the url is `http://someurl.org/somefd/somefd2`

- `<img src="picture.jpg">         http://someurl.org/somefd/somefd2/picture.jpg`
- `<img src="images/picture.jpg">  http://someurl.org/somefd/somefd2/images/picture.jpg`
- `<img src="/images/picture.jpg"> http://someurl.org/images/picture.jpg`
- `<img src="../picture.jpg">      http://someurl.org/somefd/picture.jpg`

This is my code to convert rp to ap.

```
import re

site = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAGE'


def r2a(path,site=site):
    rp = re.findall(r"(/?\W{2}\/)+?",path)

    if path.find("http") == 0: 
        #full http url
        return path

    elif path.find("//") == 0: 
        #http url lack of http:
        return "http:" + path

    elif path.find("//") < 0 and path.find("/") == 0: 
        # located in the folder at the root of the current web
        site_root = re.findall("http.{3,4}[^/]+",site)
        return site_root[0] + path

    elif rp: 
        # located in the folder one level up from the current folder
        sitep = len(re.findall(r"([^/]+)+",site)) - 2 - len(rp)
        # raise error when sitep-len(rp)
        new_path = re.findall("(http.{4}[^/]+)(/[^/]+){%d}"%(sitep),site)
        return "{}/{}".format("".join(new_path[0]),path.replace( "".join(rp) , ""))

    else:
        #  located in the folder one level up from the current folder
        #  located in the same folder as the current page
        return "{}/{}".format(site,path)


assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAGE/a.jpg" == r2a("a.jpg")
assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAGE/unknow/a.jpg" == r2a("unknow/a.jpg")
assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/unknow/a.jpg" == r2a("/unknow/a.jpg")
assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/a.jpg" == r2a("../a.jpg")
assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/a.jpg" == r2a("../../a.jpg")
assert "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAGE/a.jpg" == r2a("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAGE/a.jpg")
assert "http://en.wikipedia.org/" == r2a("//en.wikipedia.org/")
```

Comment: It seems to me the issue is with img_tags = soup.findAll('img',{"src":True}) since I'm not able to get the image tags nor its relative or absolute path from it.

Comment: can you provide an example url as you can?

Comment: I'm trying to get icons from here http://phylopic.org/ the images have html: <img data-bind="attr: { src: thumbURL() }, fadeVisible: true, fadeInDelay: ($index() + 1) * 100, fadeInDuration: 750" width="64" height="64" alt="" src="/assets/images/submissions/66511ed6-60f4-44a6-abfc-68488e98f678.thumb.png" style="display: inline;">

Comment: the reason why you can not got it , because this img need javascript to load data. @user2300867

Comment: i am finding a question i answered , which can help me write a better answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182800/discussion-between-user2300867-and-kcorlidy).